# How do I store device "trigger" configurations in the cloud?

Tags: cloud-computing

One of my spare time projects is an automated irrigation system. I realize I'm not the first one to do this and that there is a large number of similar projects out there. However, I'm doing it for the fun of it.

The system is simple :

1. Arduino
2. A few inputs (moisture, temperature)
3. A relay to toggle a few water pumps on / off.

The system will be trigger based, and will toggle water pumps on / off according to either a schedule or temperature / moist levels.

Triggers will be handled on the Arduino, but I'd like to keep the configuration somewhere else - such as in "the cloud".

The configurations should simply store a time schedule and/or moisture/temperature threshold levels for each pump.

I'd be surprised if I'm the first person who's on the look for a place to store and manage "trigger" configurations like this. That is, a place which allows me manage the configurations needed for these triggers.

It seems like a huge overkill for me to have to develop an entire REST API and configuration UI just for the purpose of storing and managing these configurations.

What alternatives do I have to manage my trigger configurations?

Comment: why do you need to store the configuration off board?

Comment: I dont have a storage on board, and i'd like to be able to change schedules and not have them in code.

Comment: check this out https://github.com/OpenSprinkler